# flutter: how to read geohash and geopoint from firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, get

The following is the way I saved user's `geohash` and `geopoint` in firestore.

[image]

For example, if I want to read field `intro`, I write this way;

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('...').doc(..).data()['intro']
```

But I don't know how to read `geohash` and `geopoint` from firestore. `geohash` is inside a map, and `geopoint` is an array inside a map. How do you retrieve `geohash` and `geopoint` from my firestore?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can read the `g` instead of returning the `intro` field and convert the data to [JSON](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json). For instance:

```
var location = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('...').doc(..).data()['g']
location = jsonEncode(location.toJson())
```